# A weird problem - adding more UILabels to my UITableViewCell crashes the application when releasing this label

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have a customized UITableView that works just fine. With 4 lables and 3 pictures.

I am trying to add another lablel **exactly the same** as the others **but** the app crashes when in my
custon UITableViewCell class I try to release it (no matter if I try to release it before the other labels or after)

I tried everything, I got no real progress but I **got those wierd results**:

1. If I remove one of the other labels from the code (Didn't touch it on IB) then everything works perfectly fine.
2. I also tried to add an image view, the same way as in 1 and it works fine too. (I did this to test that I don't maye over allocate to much memory.
3. I ran it with performance tools with leaks ditection - no leaks.
4. I created a leak to see if I am consuming all the memory - no problems, I have lots more to spare (couldn't crash it)

**HELP!**

Answer (score 0):

Your problem probibly relates to the handling of the **recycling** of UITableViewCells by your UITableView. I don't have the code handy to look at - but the UiTableview function doesn't just assign values to the cell members, but is responsible for properly *re-using*  old cells, and updating it with new content.

99% of the time when people have UITableView crashes - it's related to this. If your using custom UITableViewCells, its probably more like 99.99%...

Comment: I am using custom UITableView but I do recycle my cells. I put NSLog and I saw that I create only 4 cells which is exactly the amount visible simultaniously.

I also ran the leaks performance tool and saw no leaks.